# Number of subsets from an ordered set where adjacent elements may or may not be tied together

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations

Assume we have an ordered set $S$ with a finite number of elements $S=\{1,2,3,\ldots,N\}$. I need to know the number of subsets where adjacent elements from the original set may either be tied together as one "unit" shown with a "-" between them or separate elements shown as "," as normally in a subset.

For instance, with 2 elements, if $S=\{1,2\}$ this number is 5 where the 5 subsets are: $\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}$ and $\{1-2\}$.

And with 3 elements, if $S=\{1,2,3\}$ there are 13 subsets of this kind: $\{\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1-2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{2-3\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{1-2,3\}, \{1,2-3\}$ and $\{1-2-3\}$.

With 4 elements I have counted this number to be 34. What is this number in the general case of $N$ elements, where $S=\{1,2,3,\ldots,N\}$ and can a formula be given?

Comment: $\{0\}$ is not a subset of either of your $S$s.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It appears that all $\{0\}$ should be replaced with $\{\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n$ be the count of these listings for given $n$.
Then $a_n$ is obtained as sum of those listings not ending in $n$ (there are $a_{n-1}$ of these), those ending in "$,n$" (there are $a_{n-1}$ of these), and those anding in "${-}n$" (there are $a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ of these).
Hence we have the recursion
$$a_n=3a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}. $$
The general solution to this is 
$$a_n=\alpha_1 \lambda_1^n+\alpha_2\lambda_2^n $$
where $\lambda_{1,2}$ are the roots of $x^2-3x+1=0$. So $\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$. We determine $\alpha_{1,2}$ so that the result matches $a_0=1$, $a_1=2$. This leads to $\alpha_{1,2}=\frac{5\pm\sqrt 5}{10}$ so that
$$ a_n=\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{10}\cdot\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\frac{5-\sqrt 5}{10}\cdot\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n.$$
As the second summand is always between $0$ and $1$, we might as well say
$$ a_n=\left\lceil\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{10}\cdot\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right\rceil.$$

---

**Remark.** In particular, the formualas above lead to $a_4=34$, not $30$. Indeed, here's the list:
$$\begin{matrix}\{\}&
\{1\}&
\{2\}&
\{1,2\}&
\{1-2\}\\
\{3\}&
\{1,3\}&
\{2,3\}&
\{2-3\}&
\{1,2,3\}\\
\{1-2,3\}&
\{1,2-3\}&
\{1-2-3\}&
\{4\}&
\{1,4\}\\
\{2,4\}&
\{1,2,4\}&
\{1-2,4\}&
\{3,4\}&
\{3-4\}\\
\{1,3,4\}&
\{1,3-4\}&
\{2,3,4\}&
\{2-3,4\}&
\{2,3-4\}\\
\{2-3-4\}&
\{1,2,3,4\}&
\{1-2,3,4\}&
\{1,2-3,4\}&
\{1-2-3,4\}\\
\{1,2,3-4\}&
\{1-2,3-4\}&
\{1,2-3-4\}&
\{1-2-3-4\}& 
\end{matrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here  is a  solution using  very basic  generating functions.  We will
compute  the generating  function  of these  subsets with  adjacencies
marked and include most of the arithmetic.

First choose the first element:

$$\frac{z}{1-z}.$$

Next choose the differences between subsequent elements taking care to
mark adjacent elements with a difference of value one:

$$\sum_{q\ge 0} \left(uz + \frac{z^2}{1-z}\right)^q.$$

Finally observe that all subsets with final element less than or equal
to $n$ contribute to the count for $n$, yielding a factor of

$$\frac{1}{1-z}.$$

This produces the generating function

$$G(z, u) = 
\frac{1}{1-z} \frac{z}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1-(uz(1-z)+z^2)/(1-z)}
\\ = \frac{z}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1-z-(uz-uz^2+z^2)}
\\ = \frac{z}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1-(1+u)z-(1-u)z^2}.$$

As a sanity check we have

$$G(z, 1) = \frac{z}{1-z} \frac{1}{1-2z}
= -\frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{1}{1-2z}$$

so we get

$$[z^n] G(z, 1) = -1 + 2^n$$

subsets without  markings, which is  the correct answer since  we have
not included the empty set in the construction.

Now  for the  potentially  tied sets  we  have that  a symbol  between
adjacent values may be a comma or a dash so we set $u=2$, getting

$$G(z, 2) = \frac{z}{1-z}\frac{1}{1-3z+z^2}.$$

With $$\rho_{1,2} = \frac{3}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

this becomes

$$-\frac{z}{z-1}\frac{1}{(z-\rho_1)(z-\rho_2)}.$$

Using partial fractions by residues we get

$$\frac{1}{z-1} 
- \frac{1}{z-\rho_1} \frac{\rho_1}{(\rho_1-1)(\rho_1-\rho_2)}
- \frac{1}{z-\rho_2} \frac{\rho_2}{(\rho_2-1)(\rho_2-\rho_1)}
\\ = -\frac{1}{1-z} 
+ \frac{1}{1-z/\rho_1} \frac{1}{(\rho_1-1)(\rho_1-\rho_2)}
+ \frac{1}{1-z/\rho_2} \frac{1}{(\rho_2-1)(\rho_2-\rho_1)} $$

Extracting coefficients from this we obtain

$$[z^n] G(z, 2) = -1 
+ \rho_1^{-n} \frac{1}{(\rho_1-1)\sqrt{5}}
- \rho_2^{-n} \frac{1}{(\rho_2-1)\sqrt{5}}.$$

We may add one here as this represents the empty set.
Further simplification yields ($\rho_1\rho_2 = 1$)

$$\rho_2^n \frac{1}{(\rho_1-1)\sqrt{5}}
- \rho_1^n \frac{1}{(\rho_2-1)\sqrt{5}}.$$

Finally
$$\frac{1}{(\rho_{1,2}-1)\sqrt{5}}
= \frac{1}{(1/2\pm \sqrt{5}/2)\sqrt{5}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}/2\pm 5/2}
\\ = \frac{\sqrt{5}/2\mp 5/2}{5/4-25/4}
= \frac{\pm 5/2 - \sqrt{5}/2}{20/4}
= \pm \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10}.$$

We thus obtain

$$\rho_2^n \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} \right)
+ \rho_1^n \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} \right)
\\ = \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} \right)
\left(\frac{3}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n
+ \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{10} \right)
\left(\frac{3}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n.$$

This yields the sequence (starting at index one)

$$1, 2, 5, 13, 34, 89, 233, 610, 1597, 4181, 10946, \ldots$$

which incidentally is [OEIS A001519](https://oeis.org/A001519).

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a slightly different way to approach the problem.

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the family of such ‘subsets’ of $[n]$ (where $[0]$ is understood to be empty), and let $a_n=|\mathscr{A}_n|$. Clearly $a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$. Suppose that $n\ge 2$; $\mathscr{A}_n$ has $a_{n-1}$ members that do not contain $n$, so we’d like to know how many members of $\mathscr{A}_n$ do contain $n$. This suggests letting $\mathscr{B}_n$ be the set members of $\mathscr{A}_n$ that contain $n$ and letting $b_n=|\mathscr{B}_n|$; clearly $b_0=0$ and $b_1=1$, and $a_n=a_{n-1}+b_n$ for $n\ge 2$.

Each member of $\mathscr{B}_n$ in which $n$ is tied to $n-1$ can be obtained uniquely by appending a tied $n$ to a member of $\mathscr{B}_{n-1}$. Every remaining member of $\mathscr{B}_n$ can be obtained uniquely by appending an untied $n$ to a member of $\mathscr{A}_{n-1}$. Thus, $b_n=b_{n-1}+a_{n-1}$.

Calculate a few values of $a_n$ and $b_n$:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&0&1&2&3&4&5\\ \hline
b_n:&0&1&3&8&21&55\\
a_n:&1&2&5&13&34&89
\end{array}$$

These numbers are instantly recognizable as the Fibonacci numbers. Moreover, if we arrange them in the order in which they are naturally calculated from the recurrences

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
b_n&=b_{n-1}+a_{n-1}\\
a_n&=a_{n-1}+b_n\;,
\end{align*}\right.$$

we get the ordinary Fibonacci sequence:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
b_0&a_0&b_1&a_1&b_2&a_2&b_3&a_3&b_4&a_4&b_5&a_5\\
0&1&1&2&3&5&8&13&21&34&55&89\\
F_0&F_1&F_2&F_3&F_4&F_5&F_6&F_7&F_8&F_9&F_{10}&F_{11}
\end{array}$$

The obvious conjecture at this point is that in general $b_n=F_{2n}$ and $a_n=F_{2n+1}$. This is easily verified: the recurrences become

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
F_{2n}&=F_{2n-2}+F_{2n-1}\\
F_{2n+1}&=F_{2n-1}+F_{2n}\;,
\end{align*}\right.$$

which reduce to the single familiar Fibonacci recurrence $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$, and the initial values $F_0=b_0$ and $F_1=a_0$ are correct.

The problem is now reduced to standard results about the Fibonacci sequence. In particular, if $\varphi=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)$, it’s [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding) that $F_n$ is the integer nearest $\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}$, so $a_n$ is the integer nearest $\frac{\varphi^{2n+1}}{\sqrt5}$. Equivalently,

$$a_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\varphi^{2n+1}}{\sqrt5}+\frac12\right\rfloor\;.$$

**Hagen von Eitzen**’s closed form is easily derived from this and the observation that

$$\varphi^2=\frac{3+\sqrt5}2\;.$$